# Dynamic HTML controls through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following section of javascript/jQuery trying to create a grid overlay on a picture:

```
var $tbl = $('<table></table>');
for (var y = 1; y <= $rows; y++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var x = 1; x <= $cols; x++) {
        var $td = $('<td><input class = "chkDamage" type="checkbox" /></td>'); // hidden="hidden"

        $td.css('width', $gsize + 'px').css('height', $gsize + 'px');
        $td.addClass('unselected');
        $tr.append($td);

    }
    $tbl.append($tr);
}
```

What I would like to do is to dynamically have a class name or id associated with each of the td elements so that I'm able to grab which squares are checked for later usage.  Is something like that possible?

Comment: `$(\`<td class="${ myClassNameFunc(x,y) }">...`

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "dynamically associated" here?

Comment: You can set multiple CSS properties at once. Use `$td.css({width: $gsize + 'px', height: $gsize + 'px'});` See [the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below.

I have attached a click handler to all checkbox. So when the user clicks a checkbox, I am finding the closest `tr` and check add a css class called `changed`.

jQuery `closest` will traverse up in the parent order hierarchy and returns a dom node based on the selector which is passed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
      // Add condition to see if checked or not and add class or do something
      $(this).closest("tr").addClass("changed");
   }
})
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan: Sorry and thanks for the comment. I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that's what you're looking for: (code is working, so it should be self-explanatory)

```js
$rows = 5;
$cols = 5;
$gsize = 15;
var $tbl = $('<table></table>');

for (var y = 1; y <= $rows; y++) {
    var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var x = 1; x <= $cols; x++) {
    
        var $td = $('<td><input class = "chkDamage" type="checkbox" /></td>'); // hidden="hidden"

        $td.css('width', $gsize + 'px').css('height', $gsize + 'px');
        $td.addClass('unselected');
        $td.addClass('r-'+y);
        $td.addClass('c-'+x);
        $tr.append($td);

    }
    $tbl.append($tr);
}
$('body').append($tbl)
setTimeout(()=>{console.log($('.r-3.c-4'),$('.r-3.c-4 input').prop('checked'))},2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to track the "location" of the checkboxes in grid...

I would use a `data` attribute.

```
var tbl = $('<table></table>');
for (var y = 1; y <= $rows; y++) {
  var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
  for (var x = 1; x <= $cols; x++) {
    var td = $('<td><input class="chkDamage" type="checkbox"') /></td>; // hidden="hidden"

    td.attr("data-coord", y+","+x); // Adds an attribute "data-coord" containing a string like 4,2 (row #2, cell #4)

    td.css('width', $gsize + 'px').css('height', $gsize + 'px');
    td.addClass('unselected');
    tr.append(td);

  }
  tbl.append(tr);
}
```

In procuded HTML, it will look like:
`<td><input class="chkDamage" type="checkbox" data-coord="4,2"') /></td>`

So, after user action, you can retreive `data-coord` values for the checked checkboxes using something like:

```
var coord_arr=[];
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
  coord_arr.push( $(this).data("coord") );
}
```

So, `coord_arr` will be an array of strings... Like, for example : `["4,2","6,3",10,1"]`